# Wordpress Structure Post type for TV Shows

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wanted to know what is the proper way to structure post types or taxonomy for TV shows.

What I want accomplish structure something like following

```
- Series: Name,Title,Description
 -- Season 1
  --- Episode 1
  --- Episode 2
 -- Season 2
  --- Episode 1
  --- Episode 2
```

I read many articles example http://ottopress.com/tag/custom-post-types/ this one. It makes sense to not use Season as taxonomy or episode as taxonomy and make it as postmeta. But question arises and confuses me how would I use postmeta and query it too.

Should Episode and Series be separate post type ? and use Season as postmeta ?

Any suggestion and help would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Episodes are a custom post type, series & seasons are a taxonomy (categorising your posts). at least... I would do it that way. This structure makes it very easy to query (get all episodes from serie X and season Y) with the "tax_query" option available in get_posts and WP_Query.

Comment: If I make Seasons a taxonomy. Wouldn't it just query all episodes from different seasons having Season 1 ?

Comment: You can throw in multiple taxonomies in your query, so you can query for Season 1 AND Serie X, which would return all episodes of season 1 and serie x. See the "tax_query" description of WP_Query.

Comment: Ye but if thats a custom taxonomy than how would I show series as a page including details of series and all related seasons with episodes.

Comment: You can give single taxonomy terms their own page (it's native by WordPress). By adding a taxonomy-yourtax.php template in your theme. You can also add custom meta fields to a taxonomy with code or by using something like Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: Last quick question is it possible to show names if custom taxonomy in carousel. For example as per your structure series is taxonomy can  and i have custom fields there for image etc can we just show that in carousel

Comment: Yes, thats possible with some code and the plugin I mentioned earlier.You can get the terms in en taxonomy with get_terms WordPress function.